# Google indexed some pages with https and some with http

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

after 2 years of development of my site I found out that google for some products index with https (I dont have certificate, so people got warning that its insecure connection) and some products with http.

Can you please help to solve that ? Do you think that simple 301 redirect from https to http will solve it ?

For example one my product

http://affgadgets.com/ontraport-crm (that should be)

https://affgadgets.com/ontraport-crm (and this works too!)

Also I found out that if I type link like this /onTRaport-crm (with huge letters) it will work too. This is simply some htaccess issue or something like that.

Thank you!

Comment: There must be a reason why Google indexed the https links though; additionally to the redirect, you should investigate why this happened in the first place (are there faulty links on your site?)

Comment: No, they aren't ..but unfortunely I found out that some guy blasted my site with thousands of spam comments with https as anchor aka negative SEO. Maybe thats the case ..but how to fix it ? redirect ?

Comment: I didnt find any htaccess solution, so I did this trick 

if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") {
    $urlhttps = "http://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: $urlhttps");
    exit;
}

Comment: OK, but your server should stop handling https URLs in the first place if you don't want the site to support https. That needs setting up in the server config.